# PHP Ping Command

Tags: php

I have a ping command that pings items from an array using exec and strpos but the issue is because its look for a value ("Received =1") when the results are:
Reply from xx.xx.xx.xx Destination host unreachable the result is Received = 1 so it passes and doesn't fail.

Does anyone have a idea on how to alter this so it works correctly, i have only noticed this after a machine. Was turned off and reporting back OK and status up.

My code below:

```php
    function CriticalSystem( &$SC, &$FC ){ //pass count variables by reference 
     //array for critical devices
    //Black #000000
    //White #FFFFFF
       
    $systems = array( 
    array('ip' => '8.8.8.8', 'name' => 'Leased Line Connection (Virgin BT Failover)'),     
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.254', 'name' => 'Hostname'), 
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.205', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.200', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.201', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => 'WIN-FHPBMBL2E24', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.1', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.2', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.3', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.4', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.7', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.13', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.71', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.69', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.100', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.5', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.6', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.11', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.12', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.9', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.14', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.8', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.10', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.210', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.211', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.243', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.249', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.250', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.251', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.252', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.248', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.247', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.253', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => 'DESKTOP-AF7UN0J', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    array('ip' => '192.168.11.244', 'name' => 'Hostname'),
    
    );

    //Result to search for to give success result
    $good = "Received = 1";
    //$successValue;
    
    //troubleshooting to see if being re-freshed
    //echo "<h1>Site Status  ".date("h:i:s")."</h1>";
   
    echo "<table border='0' class='table'>";
    // foreach loop to ping IP and check if alive or dead & display result
    foreach ($systems as $ip) {
        unset($result);
        $successValue = "DOWN";
        exec("ping -n 1 $ip[ip]", $result);
        foreach($result as $line) {
            if (strpos($line,$good) == TRUE){
                $successValue = "UP";
            }
        }
        
        echo "<tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <td>IP Address: {$ip['ip']}</td>
                    <td VALIGN = Middle Align = Center>Unit Name: {$ip['name']}</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Status is: $successValue</td>
                    <td VALIGN = Middle Align = Center>" . ($successValue == "UP" ? "<img src='/Images/GTick.jpg'>" ."<span style='color:#FFFFFF'>". $SC++ ."</span>" : "<img src='/Images/RTick.jpg'>" . "<span style='color:#FFFFFF'>".$FC++ ."</span>"). "</td>
                  </tr>
             </tbody>
             ";
     }
    echo"</table>";
     //debug dispaly full result of ping request
    //var_dump($result);
    $FC = count($systems) - $SC;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is when the reply is

"Reply from xx.xx.xx.xx Destination host unreachable"

I would like the system to know that, that system is down and not up as at the moment the code is looking for the $good variable and the result from Reply from xx.xx.xx.xx Destination host unreachable the result is Received is the same result as the good variable so it shows as "SYSTEM UP" were it is actually "DOWN"

Also as requested here is a screenshot of my page:

[image: Critical Systems Screenshot]

Comment: I would like to ask back the question what you actually want to achieve with that. Because your question sounds like a classical "x/y problem": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is when the reply is "Reply from xx.xx.xx.xx Destination host unreachable" i would like the system to know that, that system is down and not up as at the moment the code is looking for the $good variable and the result from Reply from xx.xx.xx.xx Destination host unreachable the result is Received  is the same result as the good variable so it shows as "SYSTEM UP" were it is actually "DOWN".

Comment: That is just what you already wrote in your question. It is not an answer to my question. I wonder why you want to perform a network ping and especially why you want to perform that from a php based logic. That is highly exotic. I am pretty sure much better alternatives exist. But for that you'd need to ask how you can achieve what you _actually_ want to achieve. Which pretty certainly is _not_ parsing some CLI output by means of php.

Comment: That's still not enough information.  What if one result is DOWN and another UP.  You really need to post a sample of your real results.

Comment: Arkascha, what alternatives do you suggest....

Comment: Rohit, I will post a screenshot when next in the office.

Comment: @RohitGupta As requested i have attached a screenshot of the web page.

Comment: You should do `if (strpos($line,$good) !== false){` as strpos returns `false` if not found, but a numerical answer which can also be false if at position 0 since PHP translates it as `false` with `==` comparison